# Rails 4 find_by adding single quotes to double quoted string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I was having a similar problem yesterday but the answer in that case doesn't work here.

```
    state = StateHelper.getStateId( values[15].upcase! )

    module StateHelper

     def self.getStateId( abbreviation )
       @state_id = State.where :abbreviation =>   abbreviation 
     end  
   end
```

This produces the follow sql statement in the log

```
    State Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "states".* FROM "states" WHERE "states"."abbreviation" = '"NH"'
```

which has a double quoted string in single quotes which returns nothing.
I dont remember problems like this in rails 3.x. Is there some rule i am missing? 
Oh where and find_by both have the same problem

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Where is this method being called? You're being passed a double quoted string. Before your `State.where` try `Rails.logger.debug("Got abbreviation: " + abbreviation)` and you'll probably see what's going on.

Comment: Postgres 9 is the db.